# git push --set-upstream origin master

Tags: git

I am trying to git push to a remote server with this command `git push --set-upstream origin master` as instructed. it brings me to a place where I have to enter my username and password but I am unable to enter my password or token. When I hit my keyboard, nothing shows.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
vagrant@ubuntu-focal:~/zero_day$ git push --set-upstream origin master
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://skibanj@github.com':
```

Honestly I am clueless but I am expecting my codes to push now so I wont have to push with any arguments again.

Comment: You might have to add your public ssh key as described by github: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: The terminal typically does not show anything when you're typing a password. Try typing the password anyway and pressing Enter.

Comment: @Friedrich SSH keys for HTTPS protocol?

Comment: If you set up SSH it's much easier, but you'd need to `git remote set-url origin ssh://xxx` first and set up your ssh keys properly locally and on github. If you want to use https just enter your password. It won't show the password while typing for security but it's still recording the keystrokes

Comment: `--set-upstream ` argument is needed only once to setup "remote tracking branch". Once this is successful you do not need any arguments (unless you do something specific). Now password handling depends on your system and git version. For example git from apple adds password to the system key-chain so later you are not prompt for a password and user name. I recommend to use ssh protocol and ssh keys.

Comment: This is not really a git question, is it? The question is "why does my terminal not show my password when typing it?" and the answer is "that's the way it is for almost all sensible applications on GNU+Linux which ask the users for passwords". But note that GitHub has had disabled password-based access for almost a year now.

Comment: @phd haha, no that would not work. I completely missed the HTTPS bit. I'll leave my botched comment in case OP decides to set up ssh.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are working with a remote repository which you cloned from github.com through https. If the repo is public, `clone`ing and `fetch`ing can be done anonymously, but `push`ing to github always require to authenticate -- with your github account.

The go to way when you need to push to github is to set up an ssh access and access github through ssh.

To do this:

- to set an ssh key linked to your account and set your own system to use it, check the procedure on github :

  [Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)
- to update your local repo to instruct git to access github through ssh, just change the url of your `origin` remote :

  ```
  git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<path/to/repo>
  ```

You may also go through authenticated https:

- if you don't push often, you may keep the workflow you show, the Username/Password that are asked are your credentials on github
- you may set things up in git to store or cache your password :
  see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Comment: note: a second thing you will need is to have write access to the repo you push to. On most open source projects: the generic way is to first fork the repo (e.g: go to the Github website and click the "[Fork]" button) under your own github account, push to *that* clone, and then open a Pull Request on the original repo.

Comment: if this is the setup you need, please add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You should add the command `"git push -u origin main"` I hope it will work.

Comment: incorrect answer deserves downvote